# Alternative way to capture screenshots (using CG rather than CA)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, core-graphics

So my usual way of capturing a screenshot is this:

```
CGRect captureFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1280, 935);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(captureFrame.size);
 [self.bgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

However, I'm now trying to use masks on the CA layer (setting self.bgView.layer.mask). Unfortuantely, my screenshots aren't taking into account this mask, as I've been told that [CA Layer's don't render masks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9615507/339946) and that I should try using CoreGraphics. Does anyone have code samples on how to capture and save screenshots using CoreGraphics rather than CA Layers?

Thanks