# Saving the whole uiview in PDF

Tags: objective-c, xcode, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2

I know how to save the uiview in PDF but my problem is how to save the whole uiview in PDF ,for example if you have a page which it is longer than iPad display and you need to scroll it i only can save the active view in PDF file but the rest does not exist.
I'm looking for help or any tutorial which help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render a view to a PDF like this:

```
#define kDefaultPageHeight 1024
#define kDefaultPageWidth  768
#define kMargin 5

CGRect origframe = someView.frame;
NSString *heightStr = origFrame.size.height;
int height = [heightStr intValue];

// Size of the view in the pdf page
CGFloat maxHeight   = kDefaultPageHeight - 2*kMargin;
CGFloat maxWidth    = kDefaultPageWidth - 2*kMargin;
int pages = ceil(height / maxHeight); // or use 1 if you only have 1 page.

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(@"some/full/path.pdf", CGRectZero, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kDefaultPageWidth, kDefaultPageHeight), nil);
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, kMargin, kMargin);

/* this is the view that you will render to the PDF */
[someView.layer renderInContext:currentContext];

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

*Of course this is a rough snippet of code, you will need to adjust to fit your needs*

Comment: For completeness, while `renderInContext` is the best answer, it may not work if you used certain features of `CALayer`.  See [Can't capture masks within view layer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9615235/1318452).

Comment: Let me try that and we ll see ,but please tell me ,does this codes save the longer page ?

Comment: Just one more thing ,in this code you use CGRect to draw th frame and view what happen if you use storyboard ? how to implement it ? and how to add the other views to this pdf as other pages.

Comment: how do I turn multiple views into a single PDF file with multiple pages? PLEEEAASSEEE I'm helpless!!

Comment: I just found that i have to do hard coding.